# How can I convert a big database exported from mysql to smaller chunks

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a backup from a forum which in uncompressed form is 270 MB and in sql.gz from PhpMyAdmin is 27 MB.

The biggest table is `post` table which is in sql.gz around 18 MB. I tried to first import this single table to new database with PhpMyAdmin but the server always times out.

The timeout is like immediately after few seconds...I dont want to bother with crappy server support so I am looking for a personal work around!

Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: Is it getting timed out after 30+ seconds??

Comment: First make that file into smaller ones, then add them one by one. Or you can learn about the load data infile http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html mysql command, I'm not sure of how it works but it seems related

Comment: The timeout is like immediately after few seconds...I dont want to bother with crappy server support so I am looking for a personal work around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to write some code in your application to automate the process but it could be with something like

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_users` like `users`;
INSERT INTO `temp_users` SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 0,1000;
```

so then you would import the temp_users table into your users then,

```
DELETE FROM `temp_users`;
INSERT INTO `temp_users` SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 1001,2000;
```

and so on